# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, setMargins is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to make the margins between text by the screen size.

It's working good except one TextView.

Only `mon` right margin is not working.

Thanks for helping :)

Here is the code and picture:

```
public void setDaysBar()
    {

    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)
      {
          Point size = new Point();
          display.getSize(size);
          width = size.x;
      }
      else
          width = display.getHeight();  

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    sun.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView3);        
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    mon.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView2);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    tue.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView9);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    wed.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView1);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    thu.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView4);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    fri.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textView6);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, width/6, 0);
    sat.setLayoutParams(lp);

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should also `setMargins()` for Sunday - it looks like that you have forgot about it. 
If you will do that everything should work just fine.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, width / 6, 0);
sun.setLayoutParams(lp);
```